# geany returning strange results in the basis for my binary search tree results C++

Tags: c++, tree

I began to write a project today to learn more about binary search trees but while writing the class definitions and checking them my accessor was returning false
 results returning 2 and then on the next line 4196704 in the terminal.
heres the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{private:
int data;
node *right,*left;
public:
node();
node(int d,node *r,node *l)
{
    d= data;
    r=right;
    l=left;
}
int nodedata() ;
};
int node::nodedata()
{
    return data;
}
int main()
{

    node root(30,0,0);
    node root2(77,0,0);
    cout<< root.nodedata() << endl;
    cout<< root2.nodedata() << endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not writing c++ much I guess. 
your definition of variable is wrong:

```
d= data;
```

should be

```
data = d;
```

And as for why it shows some werid data in output, those are digits in the actual memory location that your system has put there before you assign this chunck of memory, which you have not yet rewrite, to this object,

and for assigning pointers:

```
r=right;
l=left;
```

should be

```
right= r;
left=l;
```

and if you wanna access them, put them public or create method to access it
eg:

```
cout<<(root.right)-> nodedata() << endl;  //if you make right && left public
```